# Is it possible to pass a function a string to be used to create a global matrix?

Tags: string, r, function, global-variables

I am teaching R programming in an intro bio course using a basic SIR model as motivation. After students get the basic model, I would like for them to vary parameters to look at how this changes infection dynamics. The code below works, but returns the same named 'dmatrix' each run:

```
function(steps,pop,IR,RR){ 
idmatrix <- matrix(c(seq(1,steps),rep.int(0,steps*4)),nrow=steps,ncol=5)
StoI <- function(x,y,z) {x*y*z}
ItoR <- function(z,r) {z*r}
idmatrix[1,2] <- pop - 1
idmatrix[1,3] <- 1
for ( i in 2:steps){
deltaS <- StoI(IR,idmatrix[i-1,2],idmatrix[i-1,3])
deltaI <- ItoR(idmatrix[i-1,3],RR)
idmatrix[i,2] <- idmatrix[i-1,2] - deltaS
idmatrix[i,3] <- idmatrix[i-1,3] + deltaS - deltaI
idmatrix[i,4] <- idmatrix[i-1,4] + deltaI
idmatrix[i,5] <- idmatrix[i,2] + idmatrix[i,3] + idmatrix[i,4]
}
dmatrix <<- idmatrix
}
```

I'd like to add the option to pass 'runSIR' a string used to create the output matrix as follows:

```
function(output_matrix,steps,pop,IR,RR){ 
...
output_matrix <<- idmatrix
}
```

I explored ways of getting 'output_matrix' to be recognized as a string, but I couldn't find a way to get it implemented as the name of the new matrix. Is this possible?

thanks!
-Kevin

Comment: Take a look at `?assign`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return the matrix from the function and do the assignment at the prompt.

```
infection = function(steps,pop,IR,RR){ 
...
return(idmatrix)
}
```

Then its:

```
model1 = infection(1000, 10, 0.4, 0.1)
model2 = infection(1000, 10, 0.5, 0.2)
```

Then compare `model1` and `model2` objects.

Comment: excellent -- and this helps me understand a bit more the R ethos

Answer (score 1):

Given your function:

```
f <- function(output_matrix,steps,pop,IR,RR){ 
...
assign(output_matrix, idmatrix, envir=.GlobalEnv)
}
```

should do it. You need to specify the GlobalEnv or the variable is created in the scope of the function, then immediately removed from memory.

This technique is called "silent loading" and is used elsewhere in R, for example, in `getSymbols(...)` in the `quantmod` package.

Comment: Creating things like that is just weird. If your function only creates one thing, return it as the return value and create it at the command line. Surely `x=sqrt(2)` is better than `sqrt(2,"x")`?

Comment: Just because it's used in other places doesn't make it a good idea for a typical user to use it at the default way of returning output from a function